# How can I move a tab to another window(file manager)

Tags: nautilus, filemanager

I'm using Ubuntu 18.04 with the default file manager. If I had two file windows open how can I combine them into one window with two tabs?

Comment: Most probably not possible yet, would be very happy if I'm wrong :-)

Comment: i think your mean combine two folders windows into one window with two tabs, right?

Comment: @abu-ahmedal-khatiri yes, OP means that

Answer (score 3):

This isn't possible with `nautilus` as said @pomsky, but there is a way to have 2 tabs in 1 window : 
Just use the keyboard shotcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd> when `nautilus` is active

You can also open a new tab by clicking with the scroll button on a folder, the tab opened will be inside that folder.

NB:

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd> open the terminal
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd> will open the default application of the selected file
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>W</kbd> will close the current tab (if only 1 tab, it close the window)
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>N</kbd> will open a new `nautilus` window (when it's an other `nautilus` windows active)
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Q</kbd> will close all `nautilus` window

Answer (score 0):

if your mean combine two folders windows into one window with two tabs.

**STEPS**

just select your folder where you want to opened. for example :

[image: this1]

and type <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>ENTER</kbd> will open a new tab, it's automatically opened that folder like my example :

[image: this2]

but, I prefer it with [Pantheon](https://launchpad.net/~elementary-os/+archive/ubuntu/daily) Files cause it can view more column view like above.

[image: this3]

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

It seems no a good way to do this. Opening a new window is annoying when the file manager is opened by other applications.

Currently, I'm doing this:
1. Open a new tab in the file manager 1
2. Copy the path <kbd>Ctrl + L</kbd>  from the file manager 2
3. Paste the path to the created tab